# What is the difference between using app engine with adt bundle and app engine using android studio?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am using ADT and Google app engine plugin for my android app and backend. Using this tutorial -https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android#adding_the_client_library_to_the_project

Recently I came across one more tutorial that uses Android Studio/app engine for app development https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae

I'm a bit confused after looking at second tutorial. What is the difference between using app engine with adt bundle and app engine using android studio? I would really appreciate your reply.

Is the app development process totally different in both cases?

Comment: Both links you posted are the same.  But no, the development process is not totally different.

Comment: Can you explain what are the main differences?

Comment: There aren't any differences.  The reason there's two tutorials I assume is because the two IDES have different ways of adding libraries.